# Is there a Meta Tag for Quantity to Sell on Facebook field?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I was wondering if there is a Meta Tag that I could use for the field Quantity to sell on Facebbok, previously known as "Inventory", so far I have these Meta tags which are working fine:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $row_DatosConsulta["strNombre_"._idiomaactual];>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $row_DatosConsulta["strDesSEO_"._idiomaactual];?>">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $linkProducto;?>">
<meta property="product:brand" content="MF Imports">
<meta property="product:availability" content="In Stock">
<meta property="product:condition" content="New">
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?php echo  number_format(CalcularPrecioProducto($row_DatosConsulta["idProducto"]), 2, ".", "");?>">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">
```

I placed this one but doesn't seem to work correctly

```
<meta property="product:quantity_to_sell_on_facebook" content="<?php echo $row_DatosConsulta["intStock"];?>">
```

Thanks in advance